# Shell Script to get data from database | put it into file | ftp to another path/server

Tags: shell, csv, ftp, sqlplus

I've been writing a shell script to get some data from the database, Put it into a csv file and then transfer that csv file to another location.

As the location can be another server i'm using scp (secure copy). But i'm getting the following error :

```
demo.sh: DEST_PATH: not found

usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
       [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
       [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Following is the script i've coded so far :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#import properties files
. <<propertyfilePath>>.properties

##############################################################
#                       Initializing Variables
##############################################################
#USER_CMD=`who am i`
#USER=`echo $USER_CMD|tr -s " "| cut -d " " -f1`

#Making the log file in user home directory
LOG="$data/<<someLog>>.log"

#Creating log file if it does not exist
touch $LOG
echo "Script Started" >> $LOG 
echo `date` >> $LOG

echo "Data : $data" (This is coming from the properties file & contains path to were this script is kept)

##############################################################
#  Constructing the File Name (File with Date appended)
##############################################################
curDate=`(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')`
fileName="data_$curDate.csv"


FILE="$data/$fileName"  (fully qualified file name)
echo "Path of File being created : $FILE" >> $LOG

sqlplus  -s $conn <<EOF

SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 32767
SET FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL $FILE

SELECT * FROM <<TABLENAME>>;

SPOOL OFF

EXIT

EOF

`chmod 777 $FILE`

##################################################
#     FTP the data file to a specific path
##################################################

DEST_PATH = $data 

echo $DEST_PATH

echo "Destination where the file has to be transferred --> $DEST_PATH"  >> $LOG
echo "" >> $LOG
echo "Performing FTP ..." >> $LOG

FTP=`scp $FILE $DEST_PATH`
```

Comment: `DEST_PATH = $data` should be `DEST_PATH=$data`. Also practically all of your back-ticks are unnecessary, unless they are the result of trying to make the formatting work here on S.O.. In either case they confuse your question, so best to remove them and edit this question with your current code. Lots of other minor problems with this code, that if run as posted means it will never work, i.e. `LOG="$data/<<someLog>>.log"` Good luck.

Comment: Thank you removing the spaces did work.And the rest of the code ran fine..